# Return a value dictionary using function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

```
    def rate_loan(self,period):
        rate = {period: self.rate}
        super(VariableRateLoan, self).rate_loan(period)
        
    def get_rate(self,period):
```

I am working on a project that requires to use the function get_rate to return the rate from a given parameter period.

Suppose the dictionary is: `{0:0.25, 1:0.5}`.
Using get_rate will return: `0.5`.

Please help!

Comment: why this is the return value?

Comment: so I can have a dictionary like {{0:0.25, 1:0.5} with period 0, 1 as key and rate 0.25, 0.5 as value. The user will input the period and the program is supposed to return the rate.

Comment: What is your question? What does the code shown have to do with your question?

Comment: You define `rate`, but then neither use it nor return it.

Comment: @futurequant489 I don't understand what is this dictionary? what is the meaning of the key and values?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the values when receive a key, this code should work nicely,

```
def get_rate(period):
    return dic[period]
```